Extract the scale and shape parameter of Gamma-distribution GLMER model to calculate the prob. densities of unseen data
I'm using lme4 to fit a generalized linear mixed effects regression model (GLMER) for a Gamma-distributed response variable. After fitting the model, I want to calculate the log-transformed probability density (= log likelihood) of unseen data under the fitted model.
A Gamma distribution is defined by the shape and scale parameters, which also have to be provided to the dgamma() function, but I'm struggling how to extract them from the model.
Here is a small example:
library(lme4)
library(blmeco)

set.seed(321)

# create a small train dataset for fitting the model
df_train <- data.frame(
  y = rgamma(100, shape = 3, scale = 2),
  x = rnorm(100),
  group = gl(10, 10)
)

# create a test set
df_test <- data.frame(
  y = rgamma(50, shape = 3, scale = 2),
  x = rnorm(50),
  group = sample(gl(10, 5), 50, replace = TRUE)
)

# fit the model
my_model <- glmer(y ~ x + (1|group), family = Gamma(link = "identity"), data = df_train)

# scale: 1/dispersion
# lme4 doesn't seem to have a nice function to extract the dispersion, so use the blmeco library for that
my_dispersion <- dispersion_glmer(my_model) 
shape <- 1 / my_dispersion  # a scalar of 1.746258 (but data was sampled with shape=3)

# the scale should be the mean divided by the shape
# this is where I'm unsure about my solution: I take the estimated (=predicted) means of the training datapoints and then divide them by shape

pred_mean <- predict(my_model, type="response")
scale = pred_mean / shape # scale is a vector of length 100, with min. 3.159, max. 4.071, and mean at 3.73

# calculate the log-likelihood of the unseen data
log_likelihoods <- dgamma(df_test$y, shape=shape, scale=scale, log=TRUE)



I don't know how to test whether this is actually correct. The estimated scale and shape parameters seem to be close, but not very close to the "true" scale and shape of the response variable.
This resource has been helpful, but it does not use mixed effects.
